# Fill the remaining space of a div or h1 tag with a pattern

Tags: css

I'm a big novice in CSS, and I need to fill the remaining space of a div or h1 tag with a pattern (it can be an image or generated with CSS).

This is the effect I need to create: http://es.tinypic.com/r/20gi92/8

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Quite a generic question. To fill anything you should consider the background style in CSS. This can be a color, image or pattern.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I've been googling around, but I don't know where to start... I have a simple <h1> with the text that has the correct width, but anything more.

Comment: @davidb but if I use the background style the background of the text will be filled, isn't it? Or the solution is create a div with the pattern in the background and then add an h1 tag with a solid white background?

Comment: @mHouses Yes you are correct. Your suggestion will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/3rNY3/

#### HTML

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>Test title</h1>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.title {
    background: url(http://ru.vectorboom.com/Tutorials/FloralPattern/final.png);
}

.title h1 {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean remaining as in, you already have an `img` or another element as the main part of the `div`. So i'd guess adding a `background` to the `div` is what you are after.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="color">
     <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>

<div class="img">
     <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

CSS for adding color it would be:

```
.color {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Or an image:

```
.img {
    background: url('http://www.lorempixel.com/200/50');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/QfwFL/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would use a span inside the `h1` and a pseudo element.

[**Codepen Demo(s)**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/hBbtn)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"> /* not required */
   <h1 class="left"><span>Some Text</span></h1>
   <h1 class="right"><span>Some Much Longer Text</span></h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
  overflow:hidden; /* hides all extra pixels */
  font-size:2em;
}

.right {
  text-align:right;
}

h1 > span {
  diaplay:inline-block;
  background:Navajowhite;
  position:relative;
}

h1.left > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 2em; /* same as h1 or same line-height*/
  width:2000px; /* some really large number*/
  background:red;
  margin-left:0.5em; /* or remove and add padding-right to span */
}

h1.right > span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 2em; /* same as h1 or same line-height*/
  width:2000px; /* some really large number*/
  background:red;
  margin-right:0.5em; /* or remove and add padding-right to span */
}
```